# Android XML parse error. new user.

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am new to XML, and Android programming.I was following a tutorial, which asked me add new line in the display. Something like hello world. I did as it was instructed, changed main. xml, and put what i wanted to display in string.xml

It compiled fine, and It got displayed. but I go into string.xml/main.xml, try and compile, i get the error that is shown at the bottom. I couldn't work this out, so i started all over again. And same cycle happens. If I just open either main.xml/string.xml, a second ot third time, it throws me all these error. 
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/some_name"
    />
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, ThisisannoyingActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name"> This is  annoying</string>
    <string name="some_name">w ha t ever</string>
</resources>
```

I have getting the following error;

res\layout\main.xml:0: error: Resource entry main is already defined.
res\layout\main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
thisisannoying\res\values\strings.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found

Could you please tell me what is going on here

Regards,
mike

Comment: Add a link to the tutorial you were following so we have better context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check inside of your res/layout folder in your project. There is a xml file there called.

> main.out.xml

. And in your res/values folder there is a file

> strings.out.xml

delete both of these. If you are using MOTO DEV this is something that happens when you select a xml file and click build. Its weird.

Comment: Thankyou. That does the trick. I was clueless as why this was happening, and was wasting a lot of time trying to see what the problem was.

Comment: Yepa ive done this about 10 times. =) dont forget to mark the answer correct